# Asp.net C# Display multiple row value of a single column in a single level

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to display all the TrailerNo from ICDTmpTrailerMovemnt table in lblTrailerNo label using following code.But it is showing the first row value multiple times But how can i fetch all the rows of that particular column like

CMDHA-610023
CMDHA-610024
CMDHA-610026
CMDHA-610027
CMDHA-610028
CMDHA-610029
CMDHA-610030
CMDHA-610031 etc

```
    String con = dbcon;
    String SQL = "select TrailerNo from ICDTmpTrailerMovemnt";
    SqlDataAdapter Adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    Adpt.Fill(ds);

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        lblTrailerNo.Text += ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TrailerNo"].ToString() + "<br />";

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    lblTrailerNo.Text += dr["TrailerNo"].ToString() + "<br />";

}
```